# RewriteCond: what is the difference between writing ^ or not?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have written this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
```

And it works the same if I remove the `^` symbol.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^ means start and $ means the end
```

In your case it will only match 443

^443 will match 443, 4431,4432 etc etc

443$ will match 443, 1443, 2443, 51443 etc etc

Answer (score 0):

^ means match start of string/line. Without ^ you'll also match e.g. 1443. And on the same note, $ means match end of line.

So, ^443$ matches 443 exactly. 443$ matches anything that ends with 443. ^443 matches anything that starts with 443.